# Snowflake PowerBI SSO works only a short time after creating the security integration

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, single-sign-on, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, powerbi-desktop

i am currently trying to make Snowflake PowerBI Integration via Azure AD SSO work.
What i have done so far:
Followed the Tutorial to create the Azure AD Enterprise Application:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/snowflake-tutorial#adding-snowflake-from-the-gallery
Asked one of my colleagues to enable Snowflake SSO in our PowerBI Tenant:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-connect-snowflake
Created the security integration as described here:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-powerbi.html

After running this query:

```
create security integration powerbi
type = external_oauth
enabled = true
external_oauth_type = azure
external_oauth_issuer = '<AZURE_AD_ISSUER>'
external_oauth_jws_keys_url = 'https://login.windows.net/common/discovery/keys'
external_oauth_audience_list = ('https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/connector/Snowflake')
external_oauth_token_user_mapping_claim = 'upn'
external_oauth_snowflake_user_mapping_attribute = 'login_name';
```

Everything works like a charm for a few minutes. However after some minutes when refreshing or re-opening a PowerBI project i get:

ODBC: ERROR [28000] Invalid OAuth access token.

When re-running the above SQL to generate the security integration it works again for a few minutes.

Any ideas on what might be going on or how to investigate the issue further?

Thank you for your thoughts

Comment: It sounds like your token is expiring.  Snowflake documentation recommends you check, `In Azure AD, verify the access token is current.`

Comment: Hm, i think that refers to the SAML Access token set for SAML authentication here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/snowflake-tutorial#configure-snowflake-single-sign-on? I have never changed that since initial setup. The weird thing is is just rerun the statement to create the exact same security integration and PowerBI connector works again for a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This value needs to be set:
external_oauth_issuer = '<AZURE_AD_ISSUER>'

In general, we have some documentation on error messages with PowerBI OAuth which may be helpful:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/oauth-powerbi.html#error-messages

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Well i filled that value in but as it contains our tenant id it does not really belong in stack overflow. So the issue is that it actually works for a few minutes before it stops working for no appareant reason. I have checked the error messages, but could not find anything regarding a security integration becoming unusable after a few minutes. Do you have any other suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Understood, that's a good clarification.   One thing I will mention is there was an issue that Microsoft fixed in a later version (and it gave this same error).    The workaround to update the external oauth audience like below (so if this workaround works, you know that you'll need to upgrade your PowerBI as Microsoft fixed in a later version): 

external_oauth_audience_list = ('https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/connector/Snowflake','https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/connector/snowflake')

Comment: I am running PowerBI Version 2.85.985.0 64-bit (September 2020). After setting the external_oauth_audience_list as suggested it again works fine for around 20 Minutes, afterwards im am getting Error ODBC: ERROR [28000] Invalid OAuth access token. I really can not tell what is changing with the security integration, it is always working just fine for a few minutes right after re-creating it

Comment: That seems really strange and I believe you're following all the right steps since you linked the appropriate docs.  Is there any issues with the access token?  If not, then potentially there's something wrong with the integration values (could be as easy as missing a trailing slash).  You'll have to check this against the Azure configuration and potentially get help with an Azure admin to make sure these are the correct values.